# Trouble initializing a $scope variable with ng-init in my HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-init

I am trying to initialize `$scope.selectedModel` to `model1`with `ng-init`. However, the following HTML fails to accomplish this:

```
<div class="productImage">
    <div class="imageGallery" ng-init="selectedModel='model1'">

        <div ng-repeat="mod in pTab" ng-if="modelIsActive(mod)">
            <div ng-repeat="img in mod.galleryImages">
                <img class="overviewProductImage" ng-src="{{img.image}}" ng-if="productImageIsActive(img, $index)"/>
            </div>
        </div>  

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the modelIsActive method that uses selectedModel:

```
$scope.modelIsActive = function (tab) {
            return tab.model== $scope.selectedModel;
}
```

Eventually I will want to use `ng-init="selectedModel= mod.model"` but when that didn't work I substituted the simple string `'model1'` and found it still wasn't initializing `selectedModel`to that string.

How can I use ng-init to set `$scope.selectedModel`? Or should I be using something else? Do I need to use `$watch` or something similar?

Comment: "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat, as seen in the demo below. Besides this case, you should use controllers rather than ngInit to initialize values on a scope" Angular Doc

Answer (score 0):

If you can, it is better to initialize your `selectedModel` in your controller rather than in the HTML using `ng-init`: this directive can have exepected behaviors.

If you really need to though, you either need to at least define `$scope.selectedModel` in your controller and then set a value in the ng-init, or use an object instead of directly a value, such as

```
<div ng-init="model.selectedModel = 'model11'">
```

(but you'll still need to initialize `$scope.model` in your controller)

Comment: Thank you very much for reaching out. I'm struggling to define data like `$scope.selectedModel` in my controller because I currently have it being created dynamically in a service. Your response led me to post a new question of what may be the bigger issue (and why I was using `ng-init` in the first place). Please take a look if you have time. Thanks again!


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28768240/can-i-set-this-something-of-a-service-within-a-nested-object-that-is-dynamical

Answer (score 0):

please put your ng-if into the inner  of repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="mod in pTab">
        <div ng-repeat="img in mod.galleryImages" ng-if="modelIsActive(mod)">
```